# How to dual boot windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I'm using HP Pavilion G6 PC, there are many videos online to dual boot, I'm just confused which to follow. I tried one earlier and I could not make grub menu appear on startup. I tried many things to make it appear, nothing seemed to work. So I completely uninstalled that Ubuntu installation and asking for help.

Kindly help me out to dual boot ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 10 with a grub menu on startup.

Comment: We can help you troubleshoot.  Please edit your question and include the details of what you tried and where you got stuck. If you need clarification about some instructions, make sure you cite your resource and tell us exactly what you need help with.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I start with installing Windows first, ensuring to leave enough free space for Ubuntu. Then install Ubuntu, set grub to install to the MBR of the same drive you installed Ubuntu to. Finally, go into your BIOS settings and set the default boot device to Ubuntu. If it boots straight into Ubuntu without showing the grub screen, you may need to set a few second timeout in `/etc/default/grub` and don't forget to `update-grub` afterwards.